# openssh AllowGroups group from specific host

Tags: linux, ssh

Is there any way to restrict ssh login from specific linux group to specific host?

I want to reach something like "AllowUsers user1@host" for linux groups.

Like: "AllowGroups group@host", but that didn't work.

That is useful because one group can login from all hosts (@host isn't specified), second group only from localhost (for web-based ssh client which forces limited shell)

I read a lot of material from internet, but I wonder that I didn't find anything to cover this problem.

Comment: Read about the Match keyword in sshd_config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [pam_access](http://linux.die.net/man/5/access.conf) module, something like this:

```
+ : (group1) : ALL
+ : (group2) : 127.0.0.0/24
- : ALL : ALL
```

Activate this module by adding the following line into `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
account     required pam_access.so
```

Also make sure that you've enabled PAM in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
UsePAM yes
```